# How can go to the first or last line of file in VS Code without having to enter a line number

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know that in VS Code I can use Ctrl-g and then enter the line number to go to a specific line.  Are there shortcuts for going the first line (top of file) or last line (bottom of file) in VS Code **without having to enter the line number**?

Comment: I just noticed you can enter a negative number to go to the end of the file, like -1 for the last line, -2 for the second-last line, etc. That doesn't answer the question, but hopefully it's helpful in other cases :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very first line: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd> button.

Very last line: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd> button.

Comment: Thanks.  I should have been able figured that out own my own!!!  The only thing I can say is that a web search didn't find anything.